# Trigonometric Identity Subtraction

Tags: trigonometry

I can't do problems such as $ \displaystyle \csc \theta - \sin \theta = \frac{\cos^2 \theta}{\sin \theta}$

Because I simply do not know how to deal with the 'subtraction' component involved. I don't even know how to subtract trigonometric fractions from each other. Can someone help here with respect to the question?

Comment: We are looking at $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}-\sin\theta$. Bring to a common denominator. We end up with $\frac{1-\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta}$. Almost over!

Comment: Seriously? You don't know how to subtract fractions? Then why on earth are you trying to study trigonometry? Perhaps you should be studying arithmetic instead. And I'm completely serious. You can't possibly succeed in a mathematical subject without understanding its prerequisites. You should try to walk before you try to run, etc.

Comment: @MPW I take that back, I know how to subtract fractions, just ones not involving trigonometric expressions. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Subtracting fractions with trig functions works exactly the same way as subtracting fractions with just numbers. Find a common denominator, then subtract the numerators.

Comment: @xsqs, keep a list of trig identities on a separate paper in front of you while doing problems, after some time you will not need it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Finding a common denominator goes something like this: $\frac{1}{b} - a = \frac{1}{b} - \frac{ab}{b} = \frac{1-ab}{b}$ and $\csc{\theta} = \frac{1}{\sin{\theta}}$

Answer (score 1):

$\csc\theta - \sin\theta$

$=\frac{1}{\sin\theta} - \sin\theta$

$=\frac{1}{\sin \theta} - \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\sin\theta}$

$=\frac{1-\sin^2 \theta}{\sin\theta}$

$=\frac{\cos^2 \theta}{\sin\theta}$